# How does a 32:8 mux work?

Tags: vhdl

I'm programming a 32:8 mux in vhdl. 
The task is based on a exam question that oviously can be interpreted several ways. The origianal task was to: Program a 32:8 mux, using "with select when", and "if then else". I did'nt get how the 32:8 mux would work, so I did'nt know where to start, but thanks to you guys I figured I would program it as a 4:1 mux passing 4 groups of 8 bits.

This is what I got:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
entity mux_using_with is
port (
         input   :in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
         sel     :in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
         mux_out :out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture behavior of mux_using_with is

begin
with (sel) select
mux_out <= input(7 downto 0) when '00',
           input(15 downto 8) when '01',
           input(23 downto 16) when '10',
           input(31 downto 24) when others;
end architecture;
```

And  for the if version:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
entity mux_using_if is
port (
         input   :in  std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
         sel     :in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
         mux_out :out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0));
end entity;

architecture behavior of mux_using_if is
begin
MUX:
   process (sel, input) begin
     if (sel = '00') then
         mux_out <= input(7 downto 0);
     elsif (sel = '00') then
         mux_out <= input(15 downto 8);
     elsif (sel = '00') then
         mux_out <= input(23 downto 16);
     else
         mux_out <= input(31 downto 24);;
end if;
end process;
end architecture;
```

Have I made any obvious mistakes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Write a VHDL code to implement a 32:8 mux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31783362/write-a-vhdl-code-to-implement-a-328-mux)

Comment: You're on the right track.  If you have 32 bits of input and 2 bits of select you have a 4:1 mux (x8).  How many output bits?

Comment: Also note the `when '0'` should be when "00" (sel length is 2) and a select statement needs to cover all possible values of select (it's equivalent is a case statement), which if you're going to synthesize doesn't have to do anything (using an `others` choice).  Your if statement version doesn't need to do that.

Comment: A 32:8 Mux doesn't really make sense to me. You could have a 32:1 mux, or an 8-bit 4:1 mux. The original problem from your other question is poorly described; can you ask for clarification?

Comment: @scary_jeff [A 32:8 mux](http://www.chipfind.net/datasheet/pdf/idt/idtqs34xst253.pdf) (with FET switches,it's bidirectional).

Comment: @scary_jeff I agree, but it was an exam question.. An i have asked two times. He only gave me a hint about the two bit selector.

Comment: @user1155120 I found that as well, but I would describe that as an 8-bit 4:1 mux, which is what it says in the description. The original exam question from the other question here seems to show a *1-bit* output!

Comment: @scary_jeff And a single select `s`?  That's a thin hook, will it hold your hat?

Comment: @user1155120 Haha! I only meant that the original exam question is not even self-consistent, and could be much more clear in what it's asking for.

Comment: I deleted the other post :) Thanks for your views on the original exam question. It's a bit late for me to complain. Can't even get i touch with the lecturer of the class. I'm taking the exam again on monday, and will be sure to ask him what he intended, and why i didnt make it clear.

Answer (score 1):

A 32:8 selects 8 bits from 32 bits. There are two obvious ways to do this (and other less obvious ones):

1. Select any contiguous group of 8 bits starting from any point in the 32-bit input, with possible wrap-around. This is actually a 'barrel shifter'. There are 32 'start' positions, so you need a 5-bit selector; or
2. Select one of the 4 groups [7:0], [15:8], [23:16], or [31:24]. In this case, you need a 2-bit selector to select one of these groups.

I'm going to assume you want (2), since you've got a 2-bit selector. So, each of your 8 output bits is actually a 4:1 mux. Bit 0 of the output selects from either bit 0, 8, 16, or 24 of the input, for example, depending on the state of your 2-bit selector.

There are 4 straightforward ways to do this in VHDL: a sequential case statement, a selected signal assignment, direct logic, or array element selection. There are examples of all 4 styles on the [Maia site](http://maia-eda.net/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=143&Itemid=284). These only have a 1-bit output, so your task is to turn it into an 8 bit output. Have a look and let us know if you have a problem.

Comment: Is it correct practice to rewrite the question, or should i have posted the new code as an answer?

Comment: You wouldn't normally post your code as an answer, unless others had posted code that was incorrect. Up to you, though. You could also post it as an edit.